# using an alternative UILabel within a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, subclass

this is my first question on this message board so please go easy on me :)

A while ago I came across a useful piece of code to change a UILabel, this basically surounds the text in the label with a black (or an other color) outline.

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect; {

CGSize shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;
UIColor *textColor = self.textColor;

CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2);
CGContextSetLineJoin(c, kCGLineJoinRound);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[super drawTextInRect:rect];

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
self.textColor = textColor;
self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[super drawTextInRect:rect];

self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;

}
```

I successfully used this as a good template to subclass my UILabels, and now I would say I have a fair understanding on subclassing.

What I would like to do is use this subclass as the UILabel part of a UIButton so that the text within my buttons have a matching black outline.

Any help or even just being pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just subclass `UIButton`, and then within that subclass make the same changes you made in your `UILabel` subclass to the button's label property. Basically you would do everything the exact same way, except all of your changes would refer to `self.titleLabel` instead of just `self`.

Comment: Thank You for the swift reply, its not give me the right result as I now have a UIButton containing 2 UILabels, one with an outline and one without. But Im sure you have given me a big push in the right direction.

Comment: @DaveSimonds  just make sure that you only modify the label that already exists within the button and don't add your own and this should work.

Comment: 2 Months later and I'm still struggling with this, any help would be greatly appreciated. 

How would you sub class a UIButton so that it uses a different UILabel? 

Totaly Stuck on this one!!